# Solve x' = -2x + 2y, y' = 2x - 5y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the equations
>   $$x' = -2x + 2y$$ 
>   $$y' = 2x - 5y$$

I got 
$$x=2(c_1) e^{-t}+(c_2) e^{-6t}$$
$$y=(c_1) e^{-t}-2(c_2) e^{-6t}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. For us to be able to help you, you are expected to ask a question (and show your efforts, but you at least have your solution here). So, what is your question?

Comment: Hint: find the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -2&2\\2&-5\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JonTrav Obviously the OP *knows* the eigenvalues of this matrix.